# I enabled multi turn option for my QnA Maker Knowledgebase. I could not have the multi turn options displyaed in test in webchat option

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, prompt, azure-qna-maker

I enabled multi turn option for my QnA Maker Knowledgebase. I could not have the multi turn options displayed in test in webchat option. I am using qnAService Helper in my local bot framework.

I have the below error.
***[onTurnError]: StatusCodeError: 401 - {"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Authorization Failed"}}***

I am using the below code from sample:
class QnAServiceHelper {

```
static async queryQnAService(query, qnAcontext) {

    const endpoint = process.env.QnAEndpointHostName;
    const kbId = process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId;
    const key = process.env.QnAEndpointKey;

    const url =  `${ endpoint }/qnamaker/knowledgebases/${ kbId }/generateAnswer`;


    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "EndpointKey " + key
    };
```

I understood that the url call is returing the error. Can anyone give pointers how to resolve this authorization issue? 
I tried to bypass the authorization but it still didn't help.

Here is the sample I used:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting

Comment: Do you get a value if you `console.log({endpoint, kbId, key})`? It looks like you are not using the right Id and/or password.

Comment: Hi Mick, Yes I get the respective value that I configured in the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

This question actually doesn't have anything to do with the multi-turn aspect.

The 401 error is likely because your `.env` file isn't quite right. It should look like this:

```
MicrosoftAppId=<GUID>
MicrosoftAppPassword=<PASSWORD>
QnAEndpointHostName=https://<YOURHOST>.azurewebsites.net
QnAEndpointKey=<GUID>
QnAKnowledgebaseId=<GUID>
```

You get the QnAMaker values from the QnAMaker GUI under Settings, here:

[image]

I made the comments in the image, but it's crucial that:

- `QnAEndpointHostName` is formatted `https://<yourHost>.azurewebsites.net`, includes the `https://`, and does not include `/qnamaker`
- `QnAEndpointKey` does not include `EndpointKey` and is only the GUID

---

If this doesn't fix your issue, let me know and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Hi Richard,The .env file is already configured as you recommended. However, to debug locally, i have to make microsoft appID and password set to null, which works fine with other bots. This bot specifically is built to support user promopts.

Comment: @Moses Why does your appId and password have to be null? How are you testing locally? If you're using Emulator, you just have to set appId/pass in `.env` and when you open Emulator, enter the appId/pass when you click "Open Bot"

Comment: I am not sure how it is allowing, unless i make them nulls, i could not debug.

Comment: @Moses What error are you getting? You should definitely be able to debug if appId/pass are set.

Comment: @Moses Were you able to fix this?

Comment: @Richard, I am not able to fix this issue. Alternatively I tried using c# version instead of nodejs which worked fine. I am still debugging the same error in the original question. The error message is still the same  [onTurnError]: StatusCodeError: 401 - {"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Authorization Failed"}}

Comment: @Moses That's odd because the Node version works fine for me. You're sure all of your id's, passwords, and keys are correct? Sometimes you need to restart Emulator for the change to take effect.

Comment: @Richard The issue has not been fixed, I am still working on it.

Comment: @Moses If you'd like additional help, please respond with your `appId`. Or, preferably, send me a link to your code. You can email me at vDASHmicricATmicrosoftDOTcom (replace all-caps with appropriate character), if you'd like.